# Are jQuery events blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Are jQuery events blocking?

For example does calling the following method return immediately?

```
$("body").trigger("myEventName", myValue);
```

My testing seems to suggest they are. If this is correct does this mean I can return values from my custom events?

```
var myResult = $("body").trigger("myEventName", myValue);
```

Clearly this doesnt work as this returns the jQuery object. So can values be returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method for this, it returns whatever the *last* event handler for that event on that selector returns (instead of a jQuery object for chaining), just use it like this:

```
var myResult = $("body").triggerHandler("myEventName", myValue);
```

[You can give it a try here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/a9dNK/).

[Check out the documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) for the list of differences from [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).